# Catch statement not working when request fails

Tags: javascript, try-catch

```
export const registerUser = formData => async dispatch => {

    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/users', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        })

        const data = await response.json()
        console.log(data)

        dispatch({
            type: 'auth/setToken',
            payload: data.token
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

In the above code, I'm sending form data to `post` route. To test this out, I submitted form without any data and expected some errors from backend like `name, email` can't be empty. But even though request fails and gets 400 from backend, it's still not executing `catch` statement instead I get the errors assigned to `data` variable.

Comment: `fetch` doesn't throw on non-200

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` does not reject on a HTTP error status, so you'll need to check `response.ok`.

```js
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/users', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
});
if (!response.ok) {
    // handle unsuccessful request
    return;
}
```

Comment: In this case, will ```catch``` statement ever be used?

Comment: @YashSharma The catch will be used when there's a network failure.

Comment: Ok, appreciated :)